# Remove items from select list based on checked items in table

Tags: jquery, list, select, html-table

I have a table with a structure similar to the following:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="classRow" bgcolor="#EFE5D3" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em;">
        <td width="35px"><a class="classEditLink" name="33" href="#">Edit</a></td>
        <td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" class="chkDeleteClass" name="deleteClasses[]" value="33" /></td>
        <td>CLASS1234</td>
        <td>A Sample Class</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="classDocsRow">
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRemoveDocs" name="removeDocs[]" value="38-33" /></td>
        <td width="245px">Document 1</td>
        <td width="600px">A Sample Document</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr class="classRow" bgcolor="#EFE5D3" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em;">
        <td width="35px"><a class="classEditLink" name="45" href="#">Edit</a></td>
        <td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" class="chkDeleteClass" name="deleteClasses[]" value="45" /></td>
        <td>CLASS987</td>
        <td>Another Sample Class</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="classDocsRow noDocs">
        <td colspan="4">
            <strong>No documents are currently associated with this class.</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I also have a dropdown that looks like this:

```
<select type="select" id="classesList" name="classesList">
    <option id="defaultClassesListItem" value="0">Select a Class...</option>
    <option value="33">CLASS1234 - A Sample Class</option>
    <option value="45">CLASS987 - Another Sample Class</option> 
</select>
```

As you can see, the dropdown is a list of the classes in the table.

Using jQuery, I need to remove any items from the dropdown that are checked in the table.

I have a selector elsewhere in the site that finds the checked items in the table, like this:

```
$('#classesTable input[name="deleteClasses[]"]:checked')
```

So I figure that's a starting point. I'm assuming I need to do something like get the checked item's name value (which is the class's ID), and find that in the dropdown and remove items based on that. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to remove an item you should do something like this:

Remove an option :

```
 $("#classesList option[value='33']").remove();
```

new

```
$('#classesTable input[name="deleteClasses[]"]:checked').each(function(){
   get values to remove and delete throught something like $(this).val()
   $("#classesList option[value='values']").remove();
});
```

Comment: JAiro, I added to my post a selector used elsewhere in the page. I need to only remove items in the dropdown that are checked in the table, so the jQuery selector needs to find checked items and remove the dropdown item based on matching the value attribute in the table with the value attribute in the options list.

Comment: THAT'S more like it! ;) I should be able to work with that. Like your note says, I just need to get the value attribute using $(this) somehow and I should be good to go. I'll see if I can do it before someone posts the answer here first!

Comment: My rep is still too low, so I still can't answer my question, but here's what I came up with:     $('#classesTable input[name="deleteClasses[]"]:checked').each(function(){
     $('#classesList option[value="' + $(this).attr('value') + '"]').remove();
    });      much thanks to JAiro for getting me that far!

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for delete checked item:

```
function submitForm() {
    var submitForm = false;
    $( '.cb-element' ).each(function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            submitForm = true;
        }
    });
    if(submitForm){
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete")) {
            document.forms["myform"].submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert('Please select an email to delete!');
    }
}
```